# How would you calculate the total sum of an increasing of its own?

Tags: calculus

I couldn't get a good fitting title, so hopefully it summarizes it..

This question can be related to almost any game and some real life situations too. Sometimes you have to upgrade a thing, but the cost of the upgrade is a linear rate. How would the cost be after multiple upgrades?

Your starting point is 0, and the first upgrade costs 200, which I assume is X(?).
The increasing constant factor is 35% (or 1.35)

The basic calculation would be
(0-1) = 200
(1-2) 200*1.35= 270, now X is 270.
(2-3) 270*1.35=364,5, so now X is 364,5.

So to get 3 upgrades , this will cost you (200+270+364.5) 834.5.

But instead doing this calculation the number of times equal to the requested upgrade level, what would the single mathematical equation be to calculate the total cost of 10 upgrades? Given the fact that the starting cost is 200, which increases with 1.35 each time?

'bonus'
How would I write this on the iOS Calculator, if possible?
[image]

Comment: This might be of interest to  you: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression#Geometric_series

Comment: You computation doesn't look right as the cost of an upgrade is higher than the cost of the product. I would expect a total of $200+0.35\cdot 200+0.35\cdot200\cdot1.35\cdots$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only equation you really need is

$$\sum_{i=0}^n q^i = \frac{q^{n+1}-1}{q-1}$$

or, written less compactly,

$$1+q+q^2+\cdots + q^{n}=\frac{q^{n+1}-1}{q-1}.$$

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what your Math knowledge is like; feel free to ask anything.

Basically, what your problem suggests for a solution is a sequence $a_n:\ \mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{R}$, which for every step $n$ of your calculations gives you the $n$-th value.

Based from what you pointed out with your example, it seems the sequence is $a_n=200 \,\cdot\,(1.35)^n$; then you need to sum all of these values together, and what you need for this purpose is the geometric series $$\sum_{n=0}^N{a_n}=\sum_{n=0}^N{200\cdot(1.35)^n}=200\sum_{n=0}^N{(1.35)^n}$$

which is a series that has partial sum $$1+r+r^2+\dots+r^N=\sum_{n=0}^N{r^n}=\frac{1-r^{N+1}}{1-r}$$. In your case $r=1.35$ and $N=10$.